# What is the most efficient way to run a regression on multiple data frames?

Tags: r, subset, linear-regression

I am new to R and looking for guidance.

I am trying to run a regression analysis with data from two data frames. The data being analyzed are amounts over multiple years by month. The second data frame has multiple categories over multiple years by month.

Here is an example of the two data frames:

Data Frame 1:

```
     name       year    month     amount    
   Company 1    2011     Jan     163237792  
   Company 1    2011     Feb     164531687  
   Company 1    2011     Mar     221592674  
   Company 1    2011     Apr     181418932
```

Data Frame 2:

```
        prod            year    month      total
Automation & Control    2011     Apr      54621.560
Automation & Control    2011     Aug      122356.656
Automation & Control    2011     Dec      73530.834
Cable Management        2011     Apr      389166.701
Cable Management        2011     Aug      505516.194
Cable Management        2011     Dec      214133.259
Cable Management        2011     Feb      352969.009
Cable Management        2011     Jan      613173.463
```

My question is would I be better served to subset the second data frame by category and then join it with the 1st data frame based on year and month to run the regression or is there a more efficient way to manage this problem?

Comment: How large are your data? What exactly are you trying to do? What in your current approach is inefficient?

Comment: I don't understand how these data.frames are connected.

Comment: You can do separate regressions or you can do a single regression nesting each separate regression within whatever category you were thinking of splitting on depending on what it is you want to do.  You will need to provide more information on precisely the regressions you are contemplating to get more specific answers.

Comment: @Heroka data frame 2 is approximately 500 observations, whereas df1 is around 100.

Comment: @Roland the data frames are connected by year and month.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck, the regression i will be comparing is testing the correlation and predictive ability of each category of what is inventory total (by year by month) on the amount of the total company inventory. Said testing the p-value of automation and control total versus the total amount in df 1

Comment: Data aren't very large, I would just merge them. Then figure out how to do one regression, and extend that to all categories.

Comment: You probably want something like: `fm <- lm(total ~ ., merge(DF1, DF2)); summary(fm)` and then examine the p values in the output.   You need to spend more time on well formulating your question including actual code.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck, I agree. Brand new to R and coding only a statistician and engineer